# Create ios framework with dylib

Tags: ios, dylib

I have 60k lines of pascal code (don't ask :-) ). Compiled a dylib for armv7 and aarch64 with free pascal. It works on device but can not upload it to appstore in case of

> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

It means that

> Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS, except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode (tn2435).

So, according to this there should be a way to create a framework with dylib. Besides there are lot of frameworks with libraries: Fabric, Crashlytics, Firebase, GoogleAnalytics, etc.

I looked into this frameworks and created my own. But now I have error

> The binary file 'test.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.

So, my questions is how to create a framework with dylib (with Function test(foo: integer): integer; cdecl;), load it and use in ObjectiveC project?

Thanks.

---

Compiled a dylib for armv7 and aarch64 with free pascal.
dlopen() works well but can not upload it to appstore.

> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Tried to make simple framework, but

> The binary file 'test.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.

---

```
library fpctest;

{$ifdef fpc}
 {$mode delphi}
{$endif}

uses sysutils;

Function test (foo: integer) : integer; cdecl;
begin
  Result := foo * 2;
end;

Exports
  test;
end.
```

---

Need working framework with dylib.

Comment: Also I tried to make static lib. Included all rtl into it, but it fails at pascal initialization.

Comment: There are static libraries in custom frameworks such as Fabric, Crashlytics, Firebase, GoogleAnalytics, etc.
Well, I will try to fix my static library.

Comment: I compiled:  
fpc -Cn -CcCDECL -O2 -Xs -XS -Xt -Tdarwin -Paarch64 paslib.pas
Made static lib:
ar -q paslib.a `grep "\.o$" link.res`  
  
Added header file myPascalLibrary.h with test func:
extern int      IntegerAddition(int nb1, int nb2);

Comment: It was ok. Then I "uses sqldb;" and TSQLTransaction in my pascal code and my app just "Finished running" just right after start with no error with "enable testability" set OFF. In Release mode it is set OFF. I uploaded my app to TestFlight and it silently crush at startup. main () is not called, it crashes before.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

Commented out the project specific parts. You can get your Info.plist and DSYM Info.plist by creating a dummy framework and copying it from there.

```
# set OUT_DIR and LIB_NAME
FW_PATH="$OUT_DIR/$LIB_NAME.framework"
INFO_PLIST="$FW_PATH/Info.plist"
OUT_DYLIB="$FW_PATH/$LIB_NAME"

# set the DYLIBS, SOURCE_INFO_PLIST and HEADER_PATH for the library
mkdir -p "$FW_PATH"
cp "$SOURCE_INFO_PLIST" "$INFO_PLIST"
lipo $DYLIBS -output "$OUT_DYLIB" -create
mkdir -p "$FW_PATH/Headers"
cp "$HEADER_PATH" "$FW_PATH/Headers"
install_name_tool -id @rpath/$LIB_NAME.framework/$LIB_NAME "$OUT_DYLIB"

# set the DYLIBS and SOURCE_INFO_PLIST for DSYM
OUT_DSYM_PATH="$FW_PATH.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF"
INFO_PLIST="$FW_PATH.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist"
mkdir -p "$OUT_DSYM_PATH"
cp "$SOURCE_INFO_PLIST" "$INFO_PLIST"
lipo $DYLIBS -output "$OUT_DSYM_PATH/$LIB_NAME" -create
```